# Pass an argument to imported script?

Tags: python-3.x, function, arguments, python-import

I want to pass an argument to the script I imported. However whenever I'm trying to pass an argument, it shows positional error: `load_data() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`
imported script:

```
import os
def load_data( api_key='Empty' ):
    os.system('pip install -q kaggle')
    os.system('mkdir -p ~/.kaggle')
    os.system('cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/')
    os.system('ls ~/.kaggle')
    os.system('chmod 600 /root/.kaggle/kaggle.json')
    if api!='Empty':
        os.system(api_key)
        load = 'unzip '+api_key.split('/')[-1]+'.zip'
        os.system(load)
    print(os.listdir())
```

Main Script:

```
import loader
a = 'as'
try:
    loader.load_data(a)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    !rm loader.py
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which python version and I guess ipython version.

Comment: Yes I am running this on ipython notebook more specifically google colab